# What's the preferred method for throttle websocket connections?

Tags: python, websocket, eventlet

I have a web app where I am streaming model changes to a backbone collection in a chrome client. There a a few backbone views that may or may not render parts of the page depending on the type of update and what is being looked at. For example some changes to a model result in the view for the collection being re-rendered and there may or may not be a detail panel view open for the model that's being updated. These model changes can happen very fast as the server side workflow involves quite verbose and rapid changes to the model.

Here's the problem: I'm getting a large number of errno 32 pipe broken messages in the webserver's process when sending messages to the client, although the websocket connection is still up and its `readyState` is still 1 (OPEN).

What I suspect is happening is that the various views haven't finished rendering in the `onmessage` callback by the time the next message is coming in. After I get these tracebacks in stdout the websocket connection can still work and the UI will still update.

If I put `eventlet.sleep(0.02)` in the loop that reads model changes off the message queue and sends them on the websocket the broken pipe messages go away, however this isn't a real solution and feels like a nasty hack.

Has anyone has similar problems with websocket's `onmessage` function trying to do too much work and still being busy when the next message comes in? Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to do this is that client app tell the server what they are displaying. The server keep track of this and send changes only to the objects currently viewed, only to the concerned client.

A way to do this is by using a "Who Watch What" list of items.
Items are indexed in two ways. From the client ID and with a isVievedBy chainlist inside each data objects (I know it doesn't look clean to mix it with data but it is very efficient).
You'll also need a lastupdate timestamp for each data object.

When a client change view, it send a "I'm viewing this, wich I have the version -timestamp-" message to the server. The server check timestamp and send back the object if required. It also remove obsolete "Who Watch What" (accessing them by client ID) items and create the new ones.

When a data object is updated, loop through the isVievedBy chainlist of this object to know which client should be updated. Put this in message buffers for each client and flush those buffers manually (in case you update several items at the same time, it will send one big message).

This is lot of work, but your app will be efficient and scale gracefully, even with lot of objects and lot of clients. It sends only usefull messages and it is very unlikely that there will be too many of them.

For your onMessage problem, I would store data in a queue and process them asynchronously.